# How to pass foreign key laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass the foreign key but am stuck with this error `Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'favorites' already exists"`
how can I pass them all the foreign keys and the normal id like `$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();`

tables

```
 public function up()
{

    Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

    });

    Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table){

        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    });

}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('favorites');
}
```

Comment: Move the second block inside of the first block. You can't have two `create` blocks for the same table.

Comment: change the second `Schema::create` to `Schema::table` since you are not creating a new table but modifying a table at that point

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct. If ever you've missed the needed tasks before doing it, kindly try this one

1) Remove or delete the table you've migrated

2) In migrations table, delete the record which consists the name "favorites"

3) Copy and paste thi code inside the "up" function with this one

```
Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');

});
```

4) Run this command again

```
php artisan migrate
```